# Can't figure out how to access object elements using $.each

Tags: jquery

I would expect the following to alert 'game1' and then 'game2' but it alerts nothing

```
var pages = [{
    "menuMain": {
        "pageTitle": "game1",
        "leftButtonText": "back",
        "leftButtonHREF": "#mainPage",
        "rightButtonText": "Close",
        "rightButtonHREF": "#mainPage"
    },
    "subMenu": {
        "pageTitle": "game2",
        "leftButtonText": "back",
        "leftButtonHREF": "#mainPage",
        "rightButtonText": "Close",
        "rightButtonHREF": "#mainPage"
    }
}]

$.each(pages, function (id, page) {
    alert(page.pageTitle);
});
```

EDIT: updated to make the question clearer

Comment: `pages` is an array.  It contains one element, an object.  That object has a `menuMain` property.

Answer (score 1):

You're iterating over `pages` which is an array of dict, try:

```
alert(page.menuMain.pageTitle);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are only hitting the top-level element of your object.

Alter as follows, and you'll get what you expect:

```
$.each(pages.menuMain, function(id, page) {
          alert(page.pageTitle);
        });
```

Answer (score 0):

The `page` parameter in your callback function is the immediate member of the array, which in your case: `{"menuMain":{..}} object`.

So you should do it like:

```
$.each(pages, function(id, page) {
    alert(page.menuMain.pageTitle);
});
```

**Edit**

If you don't know the properties in advance, this may be the right way to go:

```
$.each(pages, function(id, page) {
    for(var pageSection in page) {
        if(page.hasOwnProperty(pageSection)) {

            //This block will loop for every 
            //top-level property in your members

            //This will alert "menuMain" or "subMenu"
            alert(pageSection);

            //This will alert "game1" or "game2"
            alert(page[pageSection].pageTitle);
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: But I won't know that mainMenu exists as it is parsed from a remote server

Comment: Do you have control over how the object is structured at server? Do you write the server side also?